# XMonad windows hiding bars

Tags: x11, gnome, xmonad, xmobar

Without any windows on the screen, I have the beautiful bars (top and bottom) with all the information I need (including the app launcher). I have no idea which bar this is, but I'm guessing the top one is the standard gnome bar.

[image: Without windows I can see the bar]

Once I launch any window, the bars are hidden below the windows.

[image: Windows covering bar]

Is there any way I can fix this? I'd love to have the two bars always visible on the screen.

Here is my xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.Script
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Config.Gnome

main = xmonad $ gnomeConfig {
    terminal = "gnome-terminal",
    modMask = mod4Mask,
    layoutHook = smartBorders (layoutHook defaultConfig),
    startupHook = do
      execScriptHook "startup"
      spawn "/usr/bin/xcompmgr"
}
    `additionalKeys`
    [((mod1Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the manage docs extension

```
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
```

and changed the layoutHook line to this:

```
layoutHook = avoidStruts (Tall 1 (3/100) (1/2) ||| Tall 1 (3/100) (1/2)),
```

And now it works. The docs are showing and working as intended. I removed the smartBorders because I couldn't get the two to work together (very limited knowledge of Haskell), but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me finally after lot of struggling!!